# Where is the REPCONN research labs key?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In the "Come Fly With Me" quest chain, I just finished clearing the basement of nightkin and sent Harland away.  After going back upstairs, I can't open the research labs door to talk to the ghoul Jason again because I don't have the key.  Using the intercom only allows me to be told "stop messing around with the intercom".

(Also, the lock is not pick-able.)

Comment: You shouldn't need a key... this sounds like something has bugged on you tbqh.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Try leaving the area and coming back after 3 game days.</strike> According to the comments, the 3-day trick does not work here. You've definitely hit a glitch, one which is now accounted for on the [Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Come_Fly_With_Me).

Thus, you're probably looking at reloading a saved game from before starting the quest, if you have one available. Sorry.

Comment: The bug has sinced been added to the wiki. The 3 game day fix unfortunately doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you do: Go in FOLLOW INSTRUCTIONS, Go to the door, STOP, Look to your you will find ANOTHER Intercom Activate and vióla!

Comment: Your instructions are unclear to me. Could you improve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you stand in front of the door to the research lab is there an Intercomm on the wall to your right?  If you activate that intercomm the Ghoul may open the door for you.

Comment: "Using the intercom only allows me to be told "stop messing around with the intercom"."

Comment: The ghoul only opens the door on your initial visit.

Answer (score 0):

More than definitely a bug, if you cannot access the area at all there is still a way to get there, of course this requires being on PC.

You can type this into the console:

> movetoqt

It will teleport you to your quest marker.

You can also type:

> coc [insert cell name here]

For example:

> coc RocketLabTop

Will take you to the Repconn research labs.

Here is a list of the ID's for Repconn:

> 0007ea61  RocketLabBasement   REPCONN Basement
>
> 00081d1f  RocketLabMid    REPCONN Facility
>
> 000e5a8d  RepconHQ02  REPCONN Office 2nd Floor
>
> 000e5a84  RepconHQ01  REPCONN Office Main Floor
>
> 000e5a88  RepconHQ03  REPCONN Office Top Floor
>
> 00081cfa  RocketLabTop    REPCONN Research Labs

(The middle one is the ID)

Then once you finish using the console you then save and quit immediately, then reload the game. This is because opening the console will temporarily disable achievements, but they will become usable again if you reload the save. Of course you don't have to worry about this if you don't care about achievements.

Sources:
https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/959559-fallout-new-vegas/57300640
http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_cell_ID

Answer (score -1):

You go near the door. Go into your command prompt. While command prompt is popped up, click on the door. A code should appear for the door. Now type "unlock" in command prompt and voila

Comment: This is only for PC, there is nothing about whether or not OP is playing on PC